# Proving that a property is k-inductive with an SMT solver (parametric resettable counter)

Tags: induction, model-checking, smt-solvers

I'm following the slides at https://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~tinelli/talks/FT-11.pdf where Tinelli explains how k-induction works in the context of SMT based model checking.

A parametric and resettable counter is given as a Kripke structure by the following formulas:

Variables:

- $x := (c, n, r, n_0)$, where:

  - $n_0$ is a positive integer (input)
  - $r$ is a boolean (input)
  - $c$, $n$ are integers (internal variables)

Initialization:

- $I[x] := (c = 1) \wedge (n = n_0)$

Transitions:

- $\begin{align*}
   T[x,x'] := (n' = n) & \wedge (& (r' \vee (c=n)) & \to (c' = 1)) \\
                       & \wedge (& \neg(r' \vee (c=n)) & \to (c' = c + 1)) \\
  \end{align*}$

Property to prove invariant:

- $P[x] := c \le n + 1$

Tinelli uses the following notation:

$I^i:=I[x^{(i)}],P^i:=P[x^{(i)}],T^i:=T[x^{(i−1)},x^{(i)}]$.

He then claims on page 52/90 that the formula $P := c \le n+1$ is an invariant of this system because $P$ is 1-inductive (while incidentally not being 0-inductive). If I'm following correctly, this means that $I^0 \models P^0$ and $I^0 \wedge T^1 \models P^1$ (base case) and $P^0 \wedge P^1 \wedge T^1 \wedge T^2 \models P^2$ (inductive step). In particular it means that the formula $P^0 \wedge P^1 \wedge T^1 \wedge T^2 \wedge \neg (P^2)$ is UNSAT. However, after playing a little with Z3Py I was able to find the following model for this formula and a corresponding representation of a state transition trace with $(c,n,r)$:

- $c^0 = -1, n^0 = 0, c^1 = 1, n^1 = 0, r^1 = \text{True},c^2 = 2, n^2 = 0, r^2 = \text{False}$
- $(-1, 0, *) \to (1, 0, \text{True}) \to (2, 0, \text{False})$

Intuitively this makes sense. The constraint on $n_0$ being a positive integer affects the base case formula $I^0$ but not the inductive step, and therefore the above model is a valid model of the induction formula for $i=1$ which means the implication fails.

Of course $P$ is an invariant of this system, but it would seem to me that we cannot show it with k-induction for k = 1.

**What is the gap in my understanding of this material?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any gap in your understanding.  What you wrote looks correct to me.

Perhaps the author meant to use the property $P := c \le n+1 \land n \ge 1$.  I think with that modification, $P$ becomes 1-inductive but not 0-inductive.  I suspect the author was looking for a simple example of a property that is 1-inductive but not 0-inductive, and missed a small detail.

Good job catching this!

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer. I emailed the author hoping he could clarify his intentions but, alas, he did not reply. This is a shame since this example is used *a lot* on the rest of his slide decks.

For me, the answer is: P as is not strong enough to be k-inductive, but if we strengthen it a bit, it becomes inductive.